# Matplotlib figure doesn't display correctly when re-opening

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an application that I am running from python shell. I have a main figure

```
fig, (plt1, plt2, plt3) = pl.subplots(3, 1)
```

I have the following functions:

```
def do_select_features(self, line):
    global mode, fig
    mode = 'features'
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key)
    plot_wnd()
    pl.ion()
    pl.show()

def plot_wnd():
    plt1.cla()
    plt2.cla()
    plt3.cla()
    plt1.grid(True)
    plt2.grid(True)
    plt3.grid(True)
    plt1.hold(True)
    plt1.plot(rdata)
    plt1.plot([rng_current[0], rng_current[0]], [min(rdata), max(rdata)], 'r', lw=1)
    plt1.plot([rng_current[1], rng_current[1]], [min(rdata), max(rdata)], 'r', lw=1)
    zdata = compression.fill_in(compression.zigzag(normalize(rdata), zigzag))
    plt2.plot(zdata[rng_current[0]:rng_current[1]], color='r')
    plt2.plot(normalize(rdata)[rng_current[0]:rng_current[1]], color='b')
    plt3.plot(diff(zdata, normalize(rdata))[rng_current[0]:rng_current[1]], color='r')
    pl.draw()

def on_key(event):
    global rng_current

    if event.key == 'right' and (rng_current[1] + stp) < len(rdata):
        rng_current[0] += stp
        rng_current[1] += stp
        plot_wnd()

    if event.key == 'enter':
        f = h5py.File(db, "a")
        pdo.insert_group(f, mode, compression.zigzag(normalize(rdata[rng_current[0]:rng_current[1]]), zigzag))
        f.close
        print "Subseries added to ", mode, " database"

    if event.key == 'left' and (rng_current[0] - stp) > 0:
        rng_current[0] -= stp
        rng_current[1] -= + stp
        plot_wnd()

    if event.key == 'escape':
        pl.close()
```

So when I am in the command line, I call select_features and it pulls up the figure and everything works great. I then manually exit the window with my mouse or hit ESC (which triggers pl.close(). I then want to be able to call select_features again, but it always brings up a similar window that is all grey. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your `fig` creation inside the function.  When you close the window, you destroy the figure, so later calls to the function can't access that figure anymore.  You need to recreate a new figure every time you create a new window.

Comment: Thanks this worked...any idea how I can pass (plt1, plt2, plt3) as parameters to on_key in fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key)? that would reduce a great amount of redundancy